# beautifulsoup: find_all on bs4.element.ResultSet object or list?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I apply `find_all` on a `beautifulsoup` object, and find something, which is an `bs4.element.ResultSet` object or a `list`.

I want to further do `find_all` in there, but it's not allowed on a `bs4.element.ResultSet` object. I can loop through each element of the `bs4.element.ResultSet` object to do `find_all`. But can I avoid looping and just convert it back to a `beautifulsoup` object?

Here is my code:

```py
html_1 = """
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr class="myClass">
            <th>A</th>
            <th>B</th>
            <th>C</th>
            <th>D</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_1, 'html.parser')

type(soup) #bs4.BeautifulSoup

# do find_all on beautifulsoup object
th_all = soup.find_all('th')

# the result is of type bs4.element.ResultSet or similarly list
type(th_all) #bs4.element.ResultSet
type(th_all[0:1]) #list

# now I want to further do find_all
th_all.find_all(text='A') #not work

# can I avoid this need of loop?
for th in th_all:
    th.find_all(text='A') #works
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`ResultSet` class is a *subclass of a list* and not a [`Tag` class](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#tag) which has the `find*` methods defined. Looping through the results of `find_all()` is the most common approach:

```
th_all = soup.find_all('th')
result = []
for th in th_all:
    result.extend(th.find_all(text='A'))
```

Usually, [CSS selectors](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) may help you solve it in one go except that not everything you can do with `find_all()` is possible with the `select()` method. For instance, there is no "text" search available in `bs4` CSS selectors. But, if, for example, you had to find all, say, `b` elements inside `th` elements, you could do:

```
soup.select("th td")
```

Comment: After copying the result of the soup.find_all to th_all, will making changes to th_all reflect in soup?

Comment: Yes it will. Depends on which function you use.
Refer: https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#modifying-the-tree

Answer (score 1):

I know this is many years too late but I went down the rabbit hole the other day and found that `ResultSet` is subclassed from a Python list ([source code](https://git.launchpad.net/beautifulsoup/tree/bs4/element.py?h=4.13#n2504)); it's really just a list that additionally has `.source` attribute which is often a null object.

Now, back to OP's main question, a filtering can be done during the `find_all()` call by passing the tag type and the string it should match. This returns a ResultSet of tags (denoted `th_all` below). To extract the actual texts inside these tags, we must loop again to through it.

```py
html_1 = """
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr class="myClass">
            <th>A</th>
            <th>B</th>
            <th>C</th>
            <th>D</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_1, 'html.parser')

th_all = soup.find_all('th', string='A')  # [<th>A</th>]

texts = [th.string for th in th_all]      # ['A']
```

To answer the second part of the question:

> How do we convert a ResultSet into a BeautifulSoup object?

We can explicitly cast it as one. Then we can call `find_all()` on it.

```py
th_all = soup.find_all('th')
soup2 = BeautifulSoup('\n'.join(map(str, th_all)))
soup2.find_all(string='A')   # ['A']
```

However, since we can already do a search on the ResultSet, it's probably not desirable in this context.