# Beautiful Soup Select Vs Find_all data Type

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am new to webscraping, and there seems to be two ways to gather ALL html data I am looking for.

```
option_1 = soup.find_all('div', class_='p')

option_2 = soup.select('div.p')
```

I see that option_1 returns class 'bs4.element.ResultSet' and option_2 returns class 'list'

I can still iterate through option_1 with a for loop, so what is the difference between:

1. select and find_all
2. 'list' and bs4.element.ResultSet

Comment: See: [beautifulsoup-find-all-on-bs4-element-resultset-object-or-list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36076052/beautifulsoup-find-all-on-bs4-element-resultset-object-or-list/36101603#36101603)

Comment: Thanks, is it better to use one over the other in certain situations?

Comment: Whatever works best. Usually `select` is aesier/cleaner but `find_all` has more options.

Comment: If there's no difference in all this syntactic sugar, just remember that `find_all()` is **two times faster** then `select()`.

Answer (score 3):

You should find the answer to your first question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36101603/4796844) (linked by [t-m-adam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7811673/t-m-adam) in the comments).

As for the second question let's take a look at the source code :)

```
class ResultSet(list):
    """A ResultSet is just a list that keeps track of the SoupStrainer
    that created it."""
    def __init__(self, source, result=()):
        super(ResultSet, self).__init__(result)
        self.source = source

    def __getattr__(self, key):
        raise AttributeError(
            "ResultSet object has no attribute '%s'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?" % key
        )
```

`ResultSet` is just a subclass of `list` used to store results of `find_all()` method.