# Extracting items out of an element.ResultSet

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I found a cool python that script that scrapes player information off of [NFL rosters](https://gist.github.com/craigmbooth/6994733).  However I would like to add NFL Combine results to the data.  I have included an example below for one player.

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL2 = 'www.nfl.com/player/deandrewwhite/2552657/combine'
soupCombine = BeautifulSoup(urllib.request.urlopen(URL2))
Combinestats = soupCombine.find_all("div", attrs = {"class": "tp-title"})
Combinestats[0].contents
```

Produces:

```
['3 Cone Drill', < span class="tp-results">6.97 secs< /span>]
```

How do I get the following out of Combinestats[0].contents?

```
DrillName = '3 Cone Drill'

DrillResult = 6.97
```

For reference here are the items in Combinestats.

```
for ii in range(len(Combinestats)):
     print(Combinestats[ii].contents)

['3 Cone Drill', <span class="tp-results">6.97 secs</span>]
['40 Yard Dash', <span class="tp-results">4.44 Secs</span>]
['Broad Jump', <span class="tp-results">118.0 inches</span>]
['20 Yard Shuttle', <span class="tp-results">4.18 secs</span>]
['Vertical Jump', <span class="tp-results">34.5 inches</span>]
```

Comment: This can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36076052/beautifulsoup-find-all-on-bs4-element-resultset-object-or-list

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just use a list comprehension.

```
resultSet = soup.find_all("div", attrs = {"class": "tp-title"})
stats = [
    (i.contents[0], i.contents[1].text) for i in resultSet

]
```

Or, a `for` loop.

```
stats = []
for i in resultSet:
    stats.append(i.contents[0], i.contents[1].text)
```

```
print(stats)
[
    ('40 Yard Dash', '4.44 Secs'),
    ('3 Cone Drill', '6.97 secs'),
    ('Broad Jump', '118.0 inches'),
    ('20 Yard Shuttle', '4.18 secs'),
    ('Vertical Jump', '34.5 inches')
]
```

Comment: Thanks!  But how do I get the results?  6.97, 4.44, etc. As shown above.

Comment: @DeeeeRoy Do the same thing.

Comment: How?  I tried the following but it returns ans empty list.    stats = []
for i in soup.find_all("div", attrs = {"class": "tp-title"}):
    stats.append(i.contents[1])

Comment: is the for loop a line wise run through the rs similar to `for line in file`?

Comment: @Timo yes, did you observe unintended behavior?

Answer (score 3):

This is another approach which does the same thing. Slightly awkward to look at, though.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "http://www.nfl.com/player/deandrewwhite/2552657/combine"
res = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
items = {item.select_one(".tp-results").previous_sibling:item.select_one(".tp-results").text for item in soup.select(".tp-title")}
print(items)
```

Output:

```
{'3 Cone Drill': '6.97 secs', '20 Yard Shuttle': '4.18 secs', '40 Yard Dash': '4.44 Secs', 'Vertical Jump': '34.5 inches', 'Broad Jump': '118.0 inches'}
```